# DAX or Excel query

Tags: excel, dax

How can I write a query in DAX so if I have a data like this, where there is startdate and end date and the total working hour and I need to assign the working hours values to each day .

So what I want is when the start date and the end date is not the same date than the Hours divide between those days.

For example -

```
User     Start-Date    End-DATE     Hour
Dan      2015-02-05    2015-02-08   32
```

Here the `Start-Date` is feb 05 and the `End-DATE` is 2015-02-08 and `Hour` is 32

The difference between `Start-Date` and `End-DATE` is 4 days.
So I want to divide the hours by the difference of `Start-Date` and `End-DATE` and assign those values on each days

So the Expected Output will be ---

> ```
> User    Date           Hour
> Dan     2015-02-05      8
> Dan     2015-02-06      8
> Dan     2015-02-07      8
> Dan     2015-02-08      8
> ```

What I have

```
User     Start-Date    End-DATE     Hour
Dan      2015-02-05    2015-02-08   32
Dan      2015-02-09    2015-02-09    6
Dan      2015-02-10    2015-02-11    3
Dan      2015-02-11    2015-02-12    8
```

Expected result -

> ```
> User    Date           Hour
> Dan     2015-02-05      8
> Dan     2015-02-06      8
> Dan     2015-02-07      8
> Dan     2015-02-08      8
> Dan     2015-02-09      6
> Dan     2015-02-10      3
> Dan     2015-02-11      8
> ```

Any one have an idea how to do that in DAX or excel query !

Comment: Are your start-date and end-dates always contiguous ranges?

Comment: @KyleHale no they are not always contiguous range !

Comment: can you write up an example of what the result would look like then?

Comment: You'd write measures and formulas in DAX, but not queries. Your terminology is wrong and confusing. Create a measure in DAX that sums the hours. Then filter the appropriate time frame in the pivot table.

Comment: @KyleHale I have update my question can you kindly have a look now

Comment: @Dan so for the fourth role in your "What I Have" you wouldn't divide that 8 hours into 4 hours on 2-11 and 4 hours on 2-12?

Comment: Given the general complexity you have here, you should perform the unpivoting and ETL in Power Query or in your source system; that's the more appropriate tool for your request.

Answer (score 0):

So just before I start I have used Power Bi for this solution which is a free tool to use for personal use however there are some licensing options available. Essentially the premise is the same however there is an element of Power Query used along with some DAX. Anyway here are my steps:

Here is my table before I have made any changes

```
User        Start        End           Hour
UserA       01/01/2018   05/01/2018    32
```

Create a custom column to calculate the number of dates between [Start] and [End]

```
Dates = { Number.From([Start]..Number.From([End]) }
```

Create another custom column to calculate the number of [Hour]s divided by the number of list items. Do not expand the list before this step!

```
CountPerDay = [Hour] / List.Count([Dates])
```

Finally expand your list column to show the number of hours required per day. Note how the dates are in a numeric format. Changing the column data type to "Date" or "DateTime" will change these back to the correct value.

Using my example you should now have a table that looks something like the below:

```
User       Start         End          Hour     Dates         CountPerDay
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       01/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       02/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       03/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       04/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       05/01/2018    6.4
```

If I add the UserB into the mix with the following records:

```
User        Start        End           Hour
UserB       01/02/2018   02/02/2018    10
```

The table updates as follows:

```
User       Start         End          Hour     Dates         CountPerDay
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       01/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       02/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       03/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       04/01/2018    6.4
UserA      01/01/2018    05/01/2018   32       05/01/2018    6.4
UserB      01/02/2018    02/02/2018   10       01/02/2018    5
UserB      01/02/2018    02/02/2018   10       02/02/2018    5
```

I hope this helps
J